# Can I limit width of an elemend beyond its padding?

Tags: css

```css
.foo {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

**Expected:** 10px wide red box

**Actual:** 40px wide red box

Can I somehow limit size just with css below padding (or border) size?

**I'm looking for a simple & straightforward solution** (like using proper static css), I can imagine some workarounds like applying the padding conditionally but I want to avoid them, see below.

My use case: table cell-like element lazy-rendered when scrolling

Known but not optimal solutions:

- I can solve this by wrapping the element into another one, but that is a last resort option for me. The use case means an element that is repeated many times and heavily rerendered, so doubling number of elements would significantly worsen performance.
- I can reduce the padding using JS when width drops below sum of paddings, but that may either lead into very complicated code (specific cell types can have different paddings etc) or performance issues (measuring the padding in JS after render).

Comment: You cannot shrink an element past it's padding/border

Comment: its 40px because of 2x20px padding = 40px ... YOu can not have a larger padding then the elements width as such it is overwriting

Comment: _"My use case: table cell-like element lazy-rendered when scrolling"_ - so why don't you apply the "final" padding at the moment you are loading the element content then?

Comment: ok seems it is not possible, thanks for answers... btw @CBroe as explained in the post, yes I can do it dynamically, but it is one order of magnitude more complex code than just solving it with css, i.e. I can't reliably customize padding by giving a custom class to the element anymore.

Comment: _"I can't reliably customize padding by giving a custom class to the element anymore."_ - yes, you can. You just need to prevent the styling from applying prematurely. So if one cell with class `foo` needs 20px padding, and `bar` needs 40px - then you create rules in your stylesheet, `.foo.apply { padding:20px; }`, and `.bar.apply { padding:40px; }` - and give those elements the class `foo` or `bar` in your initial HTML, and when your lazy-loading mechanism adds the content, you dynamically add the class `apply` ...

Comment: But that means I have to propagate the padding value to the JS so it can decide whether the cell is big enough to apply the padding or not. And how to guarantee that all future contributors to the codebase will follow the mechanism and won't add custom padding by a different class? Possible but hard to maintain solution, not worthy what I'm actually doing... Btw that is the second point in "Known but not optimal solutions" in the question.

My point was something like `padding-left: min(50%, 8px)` but that does not work as percentage is related to parent element.

Comment: _"But that means I have to propagate the padding value to the JS so it can decide whether the cell is big enough to apply the padding or not."_ - that you would need to do _that_, I could not tell from how your question is currently phrased, at all. _"And how to guarantee that all future contributors to the codebase will follow the mechanism"_ - that would have been a matter of proper _documentation_. No "contributor" can actually contribute properly to anything, if they aren't told the rules to begin with :-)

Comment: *No "contributor" can actually contribute properly to anything, if they aren't told the rules to begin with* - Well that's opinionated, it paid off to me many times to write code so that other contributors can extend and use it without unintuitive extensive documentation. *I could not tell from how your question is currently phrased, at all* - I stated *very complicated code (specific cell types can have different paddings etc* - I'm not sure how would you want it more clearly expressed that the thing is dynamic.

Comment: For the record - did not find any "nice" way, decided to dynamically calculate the padding to fit the cell.